# Get SPARQL query showing after submitting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sparql, rdf

I am trying to display the result of a query after user presses submit with the value they have inputted, the query aims to grab this `input` and generate a result specific to the input. The query does grab the input as I have put the query code in an alert box and it displays the `input` from the user in the query, this alert box pops up after pressing submit of course. My code are below:

**Html**

```
   <table id="results">
    </table>
    <form>
        First name:<br>
        <input id="messageInput" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        <input id="submit99" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

The query result should display in the table after pressing submit. Therefore `table` was inserted.

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = $("#results");
    table.on("click", "td", myFunction); 
    var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
        $('#submit99').on('click', function (e) {
            var userInput = $('#messageInput').val();
            var query = [
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>",
            "PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>",
            "PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>",
            "SELECT ?spouse",
            "WHERE {",
                "?dave dbo:spouse dbr:" + userInput + ".",
                "?dave rdfs:label ?spouse.",
              "}",
            "Limit 1"
            ].join(" ");

            alert("this query: [" + query + "]");
            var queryUrl = url + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&format=json";
            console.log(queryUrl);
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: queryUrl,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // get the table element
                    var table = $("#results");

                    // get the sparql variables from the 'head' of the data.
                    var headerVars = data.head.vars;

                    // using the vars, make some table headers and add them to the table;
                    var trHeaders = getTableHeaders(headerVars);
                    table.append(trHeaders);

                    // grab the actual results from the data.
                    var bindings = data.results.bindings;

                    // for each result, make a table row and add it to the table.
                    for (rowIdx in bindings) {
                        table.append(getTableRow(headerVars, bindings[rowIdx]));
                    }
                }
            });

            function getTableRow(headerVars, rowData) {
                var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

                for (var i in headerVars) {
                    tr.append(getTableCell(headerVars[i], rowData));
                }

                return tr;
            }
            function getTableCell(fieldName, rowData) {
                var td = $("<td></td>");
                var fieldData = rowData[fieldName];
                //alert("fieldName = ["+fieldName +"] rowData[fieldName][value] = ["+rowData[fieldName]["value"] + "]");
                td.html(fieldData["value"]);
                return td;
            }
            function getTableHeaders(headerVars) {
                var trHeaders = $("<tr></tr>");
                for (var i in headerVars) {
                    trHeaders.append($("<th>" + headerVars[i] + "</th>"));
                }
                return trHeaders;
            }

        });
    </script>
```

As you noticed the query result should be displayed in a table after user has pressed submit that's why I put almost all the code in the `submit99` button. You guys should be able to run the code by copying and pasting it to your own IDE to gain a more familiar understanding. So question is right now after submission nothing shows up besides the alertbox displaying user input.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: did you check in console that you're getting data? and why you use jsonp?  because of CORS? I think json should work here. I use json to get info from Wikidata.

Comment: Yeah It only says unreachable code in console.log, and any useful links for json? I'm using DBPedia to retrieve the information.

Comment: just change jsonp to json and check in console

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix the issue and get the result... all I had to do was insert the form elements in the table like:

```
<table id="results">

   <First name: 
    <br>
    <input id="messageInput" type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    <input id="submit99" type="submit" value="Submit">

</table>
```

However it is very strange because when I try to input the `form` tags it doesn't work:S atleast it does what I want it to do now:)